# i need to insert array values into mysql php table, where separated with comma in a single row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is my table. I am developing billing application in core php mysql. Each row insert into table means need more memory, so I need to insert an one customer bill in a single row with all values separated by comma,

```
        <table id="options-table" border="1">   
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                            <th>S.NO</th>
                                                <th>Product Name</th>                                                   
                                                <th>Qty</th>
                                                <th>Rate ($)</th>
                                                <th>Total ($)</th>
                                                <th>Option</th>
                                            </tr>                               

                                            <tr>
                                            <td><span id="snum">1.</span></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="productname[]" required="" class="ui-wizard-content valid"></td>
                                                <!--<td><input type="text"  style="width:80px;" name="itemcode" /></td> -->
                                                <td><input type="text" class="qty ui-wizard-content valid" name="qty[]" required=""></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" class="rate ui-wizard-content valid" name="rate[]" required=""></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" class="tcost ui-wizard-content valid" name="tcost[]" readonly=""></td>
                                                <td><input type="button" class="del btn-danger ui-wizard-content" value="Delete"></td>
                                            </tr>                  
                                            <tr>
                                            <td><span id="snum">2.</span></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="productname[]" required="" class="ui-wizard-content valid"></td>
                                                <!--<td><input type="text"  style="width:80px;" name="itemcode" /></td> -->
                                                <td><input type="text" class="qty ui-wizard-content valid" name="qty[]" required=""></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" class="rate ui-wizard-content valid" name="rate[]" required=""></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" class="tcost ui-wizard-content" name="tcost[]" readonly=""></td>
                                                <td><input type="button" class="del btn-danger" value="Delete"></td>
                                            </tr><tr><td><span id="snum3">3.</span></td><td><input type="text" name="productname[]" required="" class="valid"></td> <td><input type="text" class="qty valid" name="qty[]" required=""></td>  <td><input type="text" class="rate valid" name="rate[]" required=""></td> <td><input type="text" class="tcost" name="tcost[]" readonly=""></td><td><input type="button" class="del btn-danger" value="Delete"></td></tr><tr><td><span id="snum3">4.</span></td><td><input type="text" name="productname[]" required="" class="valid"></td> <td><input type="text" class="qty valid" name="qty[]" required=""></td>  <td><input type="text" class="rate valid" name="rate[]" required=""></td> <td><input type="text" class="tcost" name="tcost[]" readonly=""></td><td><input type="button" class="del btn-danger" value="Delete"></td></tr><tr><td><span id="snum3">6.</span></td><td><input type="text" name="productname[]" required="" class="valid"></td> <td><input type="text" class="qty valid" name="qty[]" required=""></td>  <td><input type="text" class="rate valid" name="rate[]" required=""></td> <td><input type="text" class="tcost valid" name="tcost[]" readonly=""></td><td><input type="button" class="add btn-success" value="Add More"></td></tr>
                                </tbody></table>
```

In the above table array values are insert into single row, PRODUCT NAME are separated with comma(,) same as QTY, RATE and TOTAL, can you suggest me.
Table structure:
S.NO    Product Name    Qty Rate ($)    Total ($)
1.          flowers      5     5             35
2.          jasmine      6     5             30
3.          rose         10    8             80
4.          marigold     15    9             135
6.

Comment: `each row insert into table means need more memory, so i need to insert an one customer bill in a single row with all values separated by comma` - then don't use a relational database but a flat file. But as long as you use MySQL and don't have specific needs that you can show with precise measurements ...just create normalized tables.

Comment: ok, i'm fresher, no idea about this,

Comment: I suggest you start learning about SQL JOINs. w3schools is often not considered a good canonical source to link to here on SO, but I don't have a better one right now  ...and I think it's not particular bad on the basics of joins, so here's the link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to store array values into single cell in mysql table using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642344/how-to-store-array-values-into-single-cell-in-mysql-table-using-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is example one , i tried this code work fine.

```
<?php
include 'connection/db_connection.php';
if(isset($_REQUEST['save'])) {
$product_name = implode(",", $_REQUEST["product"]);
print $product_name;
}
$query="insert into product (product_name) values('".$product_name."')";
$sql=mysql_query($query);
if($sql) 
echo "success";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" method="post">
<input type="text" name="product[]" value="rose">
<input type="text" name="product[]" value="garlands">
<input type="text" name="product[]" value="marigold">
<input type="text" name="product[]" value="jasmine">
<input type="text" name="product[]" value="jasmine garlands">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```